# What's the need for function heads in multiple clauses?

Tags: elixir

I'm new to Elixir and quite frankly, can't understand why function heads are needed when we have multiple clauses with default values. From the official docs:

> If a function with default values has multiple clauses, it is required
>   to create a function head (without an actual body) for declaring
>   defaults:
>
> ```
> defmodule Concat do
>   def join(a, b \\ nil, sep \\ " ")
>
>   def join(a, b, _sep) when is_nil(b) do
>     a
>   end
>
>   def join(a, b, sep) do
>     a <> sep <> b
>   end
> end
>
> IO.puts Concat.join("Hello", "world")      #=> Hello world
> IO.puts Concat.join("Hello", "world", "_") #=> Hello_world
> IO.puts Concat.join("Hello")               #=> Hello
> ```

I read this and I'm like "Why?". What does this accomplish? It's not as if the two clauses are ambiguous and the compiler won't be able to deduce the right call. Besides, I just don't see how adding a function header helps.

It's likely I'm overlooking something very simple, so I'll be happy to have it explained to me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Erlang functions (and therefore Elixir functions) are defined by *two* entities: name and arity. In your example, `def join(a, b \\ nil, sep \\ " ")` is still of arity `3` and when the compiler finds the call like `join("hello", "world")`, she knows that it should be routed to `join/3`, passing `"world"` as the second parameter and using a default value for the third one.

If we were allowed to specify default parameters in the function bodies itself, without having this *function head*, we could end up with:

```
def join(a, b \\ nil, sep), do: "default b"
def join(a, b, sep \\ nil), do: "default sep"
```

making a compiler to get stuck on call to `join("hello", 42)`.

Please note, that you are requested for the head function if and only one or more of functions signatures has default parameter(s).

The goal of head function is to *explicitly define the signature* when called without default parameters values (`join("hello")`.)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer made me realize I don't understand default arguments in Elixir fully (I wonder who downvoted it!). Give me a few minutes and I'll come back with questions or acceptance. :-)

Comment: Why would the compiler "get stuck"? If it were allowed (as it used to be), it would match with the first one, just like it does for any other situation where it has multiple matches.

Comment: @dave As it used to be? Would it be possible for you to dig up the pull request that changed this? It might have more explanation.

Comment: @dotslash it’s between 0.7.0 and 0.10.0. Those eras Elixir was not yet a mature language, so it was kinda appending a required functionality rather than improving the existing functionality.

Comment: I think @dave might be right here that that compiler won't get stuck. The docs at http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/modules.html#default-arguments have an example of a similar case, but the compiler issues a warning that first clause will match by default. I'm really beginning to think this is a hygiene feature.

Comment: The case in the example is by no means similar: the signatures of these functions _differ_.

Comment: @mudasobwa Agree on that.

Comment: @mudasobwa so, in your example `def join(a, b \\ nil, sep \\ " ")` as the function head would result in `join("hello", 42)` being interpreted as `a = "hello", b = 42, sep = " "`? If yes, then I think I've understood your answer and the need surrounding function heads.

Comment: Yes, of course. While you are still allowed to have a default function parameter in the middle of parameters list (`def join(a, b \\ nil, sep)`,) this is not possible for multiple match clauses.

Answer (score 3):

The only concrete benefit you get from this is that your default arguments will apply to all function calls.  If the compiler let you do it the way you are suggesting, the equivalent would look like:

```
def join(a, b \\ nil, _sep \\ " ") when is_nil(b) do
    a
end

def join(a, b \\ nil, _sep \\ " ") do
    a <> sep <> b
end
```

The intent of it, from what I understand, is simply to reduce the confusion that can arise with defaults.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. So it's more of a convenience combined with safety. Makes sense now. :-)

Comment: @mudasobwa Oops. :-)

Comment: @mudasobwa how is this incorrect? he asked specifically about situations where it was unambiguous which function to call

Comment: I don't think your answer is incorrect, but @mudasobwa gave me the complete picture. :-)

Comment: “is simply to reduce the confusion”—here. It is not about to reduce the confusion. It is about to eliminate it to make it ever possible to declare functions with different clauses/guards with defaults. “If the compiler let you do it”—this sentence is also confusing; the compiler not “does not want” to allow, it has no ability to allow.

Comment: It used to allow it, of course it has the ability to allow it

Comment: OK, you’ve finally convinced me this answer is correct, would you mind to modify it a bit somehow so that I could retract my downvote? Thanks and sorry.